# Android fragment optimization

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, tablet

I am trying to develop the master-child page concept using master-detail flow of Android but it comes to the execution , the design is vulnerable to the critics about the poor performance. Would you please tell me some guidelines to increase the performance besudes loading bitmaps with options ?

The below is my code for fragment

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.aaa.demo.asynctask.ResubmitOrder;
import com.aaa.demo.util.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MoreActivity extends Fragment
{   

    private Bundle parameter; 
    private FileManager fileMan;
    private SalesOrderRetransmitDbAdapter soDbRetransmitHelper;




    public class RecordAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        Context context;
        private List<String> data;

        RecordAdapter(List<String> data, Context context)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return data.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return data.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.more_item, null);
            }

            final String item = data.get(position);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.more_item);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(FileUtil.readImage(context, item + ".png"));
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("more_update"))
                    {                   
                        ((ActivityInTab) getActivity()).switchToFragment(new UpdateContentActivity());
                        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                    }
                    else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("more_building"))
                    {                   

                        parameter   = new Bundle();
                        parameter.putString("salesid", MainActivity.useridStatic);
                        Fragment s = new EOrderSystemBuildList();
                        s.setArguments(parameter);                                          
                        ((ActivityInTab) getActivity()).switchToFragment(s);

                    }
                    else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("more_qc"))
                    {                   
                        parameter   = new Bundle();
                        parameter.putString("salesid", MainActivity.useridStatic);                  
                        Fragment s = new EOrderList();
                        s.setArguments(parameter);                                          
                        ((ActivityInTab) getActivity()).switchToFragment(s);


                    }
                    else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("more_password"))
                    {                   
                        parameter   = new Bundle();
                        parameter.putString("salesid", MainActivity.useridStatic );
                        Fragment s = new EOrderChangePassword();
                        s.setArguments(parameter);                                          
                        ((ActivityInTab) getActivity()).switchToFragment(s);


                    }
                    else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("more_logout"))
                    {                                           
                        getActivity().finish();
                        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                    }
                    else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("more_resubmit"))
                    {               
                        ResubmitOrder resubmit = new ResubmitOrder(getActivity());
                        resubmit.execute(MainActivity.useridStatic + "|" +  MainActivity.isFollowup);

                    }   
                }               
            });

            return v;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_more, container, false);      
        ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
        records.add("more_building");
        records.add("more_qc");
        records.add("more_password");
        records.add("more_logout");
        records.add("more_update");

        fileMan = new FileManager();
        int count = fileMan.loadRecordRecursiveCount("SV_recordings","sales_recording");        
        Log.d("file count " , String.valueOf(count));


        soDbRetransmitHelper= new SalesOrderRetransmitDbAdapter(getActivity());
        soDbRetransmitHelper.open();
        Cursor bu = soDbRetransmitHelper.fetchAllUnSubmitOrder(MainActivity.useridStatic);
        bu.moveToFirst();
        int data = bu.getCount();
        Log.d("data count " , String.valueOf(data));

        if(count > 0 || data > 0  ){
            records.add("more_resubmit");   
        }   
        bu.close();     
        soDbRetransmitHelper.close();

        GridView gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.more_gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new RecordAdapter(records, getActivity()));     
        return v;
    }
}
```